# Architecture using `ur_modern_driver`

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, universal-robot, ur10, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building an architecture for my application and I'd like to know if the functionality represented in the `ur_modern_driver` part (image below) is correct. This is follow-up of [action-completion](https://answers.ros.org/question/285345/action-completion-from-ur-controller/).

[image: ur_modern_driver Arch]

I've put `Joint velocities` as by-default the driver publishes `speedj` commands.

Many thanks to @gvdhoorn and Thomas Timm in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285533/architecture-using-%60ur_modern_driver%60/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is not correct.

`ur_modern_driver` only provides an action *server*.

Your node(s) is (are) the action client(s).

> I've put `Joint velocities` as by-default the driver publishes `speedj` commands.

that is also not correct.

When not using `ros_control`, the driver uses `servoj(..)` in a small program that runs on the controller.

When using `ros_control`, it either uses `speedj(..)` when the velocity interface of the hw iface is used, or `servoj(..)` again for the position part.

The driver also doesn't publish anything to the controller. It's a regular TCP/IP connection over which a minimal, custom protocol is run.

---

Edit: it's a bit lame, but "read the source" is probably still good advice in this case: [ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/tree/9397f47ac158fe5976719f33101334371bc15d44).

But as I wrote before: you might want to look into the Zagitta fork (PR#120).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-15**:
I'll change the Action client node. The action server takes robot parameters (robot IP, max payload, max velocity etc) from the ROS Param server, am I correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-15**:
Well, that depends a bit on how you interpret things: "the action server" is a small part of the driver node. Personally I would say that the driver reads ROS parameters from the parameter server. The action server is just one way to interact with the driver.